# How to disable/readonly some checkboxes from a MultiCheckbox?

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, frameworks

I have a Zend_Form_Element_Multicheckbox and I want to put some of its elements in a readonly state, how do I do that?

```
    $colId = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('colId');
    $colId->setLabel('Col ID')
        ->setMultiOptions(array_flip(array('sadda', 'asss'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
$colId
    ->setMultiOptions(array_flip(array('sadda', 'asss'))) // three closing-brackets 
    ->setAttrib('disable', array('sadda', 'asss'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It works; be sure to use "disable" and not "disabled" in your setAttrib.